# SAPUI5: get model-data of current select

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a detail page (Master/Detail), where I get the key of a model as a parameter:

```
onRoutePatternMatched : function(oEvent) {
            var key= oEvent.getParameter("arguments").key;
            var oViewModel = this.getView().getModel("model");
            var _sProductPath = "model>/ZSDATLOG_MACHMODELSet('" + key+ "')";

            this.getView().setBindingContext(oViewModel);
            this.getView().bindElement({
                path: _sProductPath
            });
```

Now I successfully display the detail data in the view.

Now I want to read the current row of the model in a further function of the controller.

```
    btnPress : function() {
        var context = this.getView().getBindingContext();
        var object = context.getProperty("/");
```

With this code I nearly get my elements:

[image]

Now that object is in my variable `object`.
How should I get the attribute `Agr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should use `var context = this.getView().getBindingContext("model");` as you are using a named model.

then you can use something like

```
var agr = context.getProperty("Agr");
```

or you can access the member of your object with

```
var agr = object.Agr;
```

---

If you want to access a object member like *ZSDATLOG_MACHMODELSet('VBP00099999000117')* you can use this syntax:

```
var agr = object["ZSDATLOG_MACHMODELSet('VBP00099999000117')"].Agr;
```